# In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") error in R

Tags: r, r-sp

I am trying to re-project my shape-file into meter-projected coordinate system. Earlier my following code was working fine:

```r
country_Andorra_proj <-spTransform(country_Andorra,CRS("+init=epsg:3035"))
```

But now this throwing error as follows:

> Warning message:
> In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") :
> Discarded datum European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989 in CRS definition*

Comment: Same problem here. Worked fine yesterday. Could be a bug

Comment: Can you tell us where do you get this "country_andorra" shapefile so we can try to help ?